# Load all controllers together in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I am developing first application using node.js (express) and angular.js. I had all the controllers in a single file at the front end and I was loading that one single file using `'<script src= ''>'` but now I would like to split up the controllers to different files. Is there any efficient way to load all controllers than writing many script tags to load all the controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You typically use multiple files during development to easily know where each component is and ease the team work and the debugging. But a build process should generate the final application. This build process typically has the following parts:

- linting the code to detect coding errors or bad practices
- executing the unit tests
- concatenating and minifying the script files to avoid loading all the files separately
- generating an HTML page from the one used in development where all the `<script>` files for every component are replaced by a single one loading the unique minified JS file generating at the previous step
- executing the e2e tests

Typically, gulp or grunt are used to do this.

Comment: Any upside of loading individual files on dev opposed to concat/minify to load single file with sourcemaps?

Comment: @JimL I really never really tried this way, but I like being able to edit a file, hit F5, and see the result.

Comment: just use a watch in your build tool, working on a angular project atm with watches on vendor files, app js files, app sass files, etc. App js files build in under 12 ms, which means "edit ctrl-s alt-tab f5" works like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, I am finding out the way to get it done using grunt :)

Comment: @JBNizet: When we use gruntfile.js to load js files will it load all the files before it loads the first route? To load the  Gruntfile.js should we call it externally? is there any way to load Gruntfile.js when the server starts? (currently I am using the command 'grunt' which internally starts the server)